# Initialize final variable within constructor in another method

Tags: java, android

I have a problem which isn't really that big, but still gives me some thought as to how Java constructors and methods are used.

I have a constant representing a radius I declare final, and also make it public for everyone to see. I don't want my code littered with getRadius() methods when I'm never ever going to change the radius.

I want to initialize the constant within the constructor as I want to apply certain criteria before assigning the radius, certain conditions have to be met. However, these conditions do take up some space, and I'd like to put them in some other method, to make the constructor cleaner.

The whole thing would initially look like this

```
public MyProblematicClass {
   public final int radius;
   public MyProblematicClass(... variables ...) {
      if(... long criteria ...) {
         radius = n;
      }
   }
}
```

and I'd love it to end up like

```
public MyProblematicClass {
       public final int radius;
       public MyProblematicClass(... variables ...) {
          this.setRadiuswithCriteria(criteria);
}

private void setRadiuswithCriteria(criteria crit) {
   if(... crit ...) {
      radius = n;
   }
```

I understand that I could potentially use the method for other purposes and that's the reason for giving me a 'blank field RADIUS may not have been initialized, so I'd like to know if there is a way to add a method which will only be used in constructors, for cleanliness's sake.

Comment: All CAPS is a convention used for constants (aka. static members) in Java and not finals which don't change, just use the normal naming strategy for radius.

Comment: declare your RADIUS variable private, and allow access to it only via getRadius..

read more about Immutable objects, and how to restrict changing values of their variables

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma Thanks for pointing that out, don't know too much about naming conventions other than the basics... I specifically do all caps to know outside of the declaring code which variables I can't modify, I'll correct that in the question.

Comment: @RedOrav: It is never too late for getting started with new stuff. Here is the official [naming convention link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) right from the horses's mouth. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about (using small caps for radius, because it is not a constant, as pointed out in the comments):

```
public MyProblematicClass(... variables ...) {
    radius = getRadiusWithCriteria(criteria);
}

private int getRadiusWithCriteria(criteria crit) {
   if(... crit ...) {
      return n;
   } else {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Function doesn't always return value. Only C allows that, not Java.

Comment: @peenut I don't understand your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: @assylias I think he means you don't always return a value, and that's a compiler error. I'd have a default value of 0 if none of the criteria is met or something. I think this solution is great and simple, but say I had two final variables inside the method, radius1 and radius2.

Comment: @RedOrav Ah ok now I understand. The code was clearly an incomplete example where I just copied/pasted your code, and there would be other criterias. Will edit.

Comment: @RedOrav If you have 2 variables, you can either use 2 methods, or have the getRadius method return a list/array of results that you can then allocate to your 2 variables in your constructor.

Comment: @assylias Yup, that second suggestion's awesome, thank you so much, I was so into the question I couldn't see the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assign to final variable outside constructor. As you said, method:

```
setRadiuswithCriteria(criteria crit) {
   if(... crit ...) {
      RADIUS = n;
   }
```

Can be used outside constructor.

And you must set final variable to some value in constructor, not just after checking some criteria (always, not sometimes).

However, you might move the code outside the constructor, using the returned value of some function. Example:

```
class MyClass {
    private final double i;
    public MyClass() {
        i = someCalculation();
    }
    private double someCalculation() {
        return Math.random();
    }
}
```

Comment: I check my criteria inside the constructor, I just want to put it all in another function for tidyness. I'll upvote this answer too although it's the same as assylias.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing like this?

```
public MyProblematicClass {
    public final int RADIUS;
    public MyProblematicClass(... variables ...) {
       RADIUS = this.setRadiuswithCriteria(criteria);
}

private int setRadiuswithCriteria(criteria crit) {
if(... crit ...) {
    return n;
}
return 0;
}
```